# Dockerfile COPY file into right container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 docker containers. One running tomcat and the other running mysql. I want to copy a  `.sql` file into the already existing "docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" folder of the mysql container.

I used the following command in my Dockerfile:

```
COPY test.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

After both containers are started I saw that the folder "docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" was **created** in my tomcat container and the `test.sql` was copied into it. 
The file isn't copied where I need it to be. `test.sql` wasnt copied into the mysql container.

What can I do?

docker-compose.xml:

```
version: "2"

services:
    db: 
        image: mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD="true"

    myapp:
        build: ./myapp
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
            - 3306:3306
```

Comment: You have separate docker files for  your containers right?

Comment: No I'm doing it in one. I use docker-compose structure.

Comment: can you please post your docker compose yaml file?

Comment: added it to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build your own image for the database container with a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mysql
COPY test.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Answer (score 2):

You are building `tomcat` container, But using `Mysql` image there, Thats why the file copied to `tomcat` container.

When containers are up you can `docker cp` the file manually to the desired location.

If you want to have the database available to container at startup, I suggest you use a dummy container with mounted local filesystem. Then restore the database manually in that container. Then remove the container and modify dockerfile like this:

```
version: "2"

services:
    db: 
        image: mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD="true"
        volumes:
          - /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql

    myapp:
        build: ./myapp
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
            - 3306:3306
```

Another way would be creating your own image using following `dockerfile`:

```
FROM mysql
COPY test.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Comment: I know about docker cp but I need the file to be copied before startup I guess. (And I don't want to copy it at every startup)
So what can I do concretly to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

tomcat container is build via docker file, where as mysql container(db) is build via the docker image name "mysql".

You can mount the volume with current folder (host) to "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" inside the container.

new docker-compose.yml will look like this.

```
version: "2"

services:
  db: 
    image: mysql
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD="true"

    volumes:
        - .:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
 myapp:
    build: ./myapp
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
        - 3306:3306
```